# Contravariant vector notation and intuition

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a definition here which says

A vector field $V$ is a contravariant tensor of order one provided its components $T^i$ and $\bar T^i$ relative to the coordinate system $(x^i)$ and $ (\bar x^i)$ obey the law of transformation $$\bar T^i = T^r \frac{\partial \bar x^i}{\partial x^r}$$

What is the intuition behind this definition?

What is $r$ in this definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $r$ is to be summed over. This is called the "Einstein summation notation". Whenever you see an index (in differential geometry) being used as both an upper index and a lower index in the same formula, it usually means to sum over that index, and they just don't write the summation sign. So this really means:

$$ \overline{T}^i = \sum_r T^r \frac{\partial \bar{x}^i}{\partial x^r} $$

The intuition is that changing coordinates is just the same as multiplying by the Jacobian matrix of the coordinate change. That is, multiply the vector $(T^1,\dots,T^n)$ by the Jacobian matrix $\displaystyle \left( \frac{\partial \bar{x}^i}{\partial x^j} \right)_{i,j=1}^n$.